# Was I wrong to answer my own question?

Tags: discussion, downvotes, self-answer

I found some information about the relationship between the `System.Windows.Documents` namespace and the `Presentation Framework` assembly which I thought was non-obvious because usually the namespace has the same name to the assembly you need (it's not mentioned in the [MSDN article for System.Windows.Documents](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents%28v=vs.110%29.aspx))

I posted [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28189112/the-type-or-namespace-name-documents-does-not-exist-in-the-namespace-system-w) and immediately answered it because I thought it was a useful piece of information. I thought this was okay because [this blog post](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/) seems quite enthusiastic to encourage it.

However, I got discouraging comments and both my question and answer were downvoted.

I'm just trying to understand what I did wrong here - I've tried to critically review my question and answer - the question is a bit short, but IMO there's not really much to say about the matter, and it is difficult to frame a good question when you already know the solution.

The answer shows my lack of a deep understanding on namespaces/assemblies, but I believe my question and answer were in good faith.

Please, could you help me understand what I did wrong?

Comment: It's perfectly acceptable to answer your own question -- the person commenting is probably misinformed in that regard.

Comment: In addition to what Qantas said, it could be that somebody thinks it's simply not a good/useful question and answer. I can't comment on that as I don't have any idea of .Net and WPF, but keep in mind that while answering your own question is fine, the question should still meet the standard SO quality and usefullnes requirements.

Comment: Every time this comes up I feel like we need a PSA on this feature. [Like we didn't already have one before...](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132886/what-is-this-answer-your-own-question-jazz)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, where people who know a lot forgot that they too, once had to learn.

Comment: @Dropped.on.Caprica your comment doesn't really make any sense. It feels like an "elitist" sneer, which doesn't apply here at all.

Answer (score 15):

Obligatory *"I didn't downvote, but"* - the problem is not the self-answering; it's the question itself, which I addressed in [my comment to your question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28189112/the-type-or-namespace-name-documents-does-not-exist-in-the-namespace-system-w#comment44750434_28189112):

> Do we want a question like this for every namespace in .NET? The question *"How to find in which assembly a type resides"* is *"Check MSDN"*. For example the type [`System.Windows.Documents.DocumentPage` is, according to MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.documentpage(v=vs.110).aspx), in "Assembly: PresentationCore (in PresentationCore.dll)".

I think the question is too localized *for a self-answered question*, and in fact - the broader question has been asked before, see *[How to find an assembly name for a .NET namespace, for example, Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7704456)*, which in turn links to *[How do I know what reference to include to import a specific .NET namespace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1165462)*, both in which you'll read the same as in that comment.

I think that sentiment is reflected by the downvotes.

Comment: I agree that the question is too localized *for a self-answer*. If the question was "I get this error and (hypothetically) couldn't find what to do", someone would answer, "add the missing assembly which you can find how to do [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7704456)". It's a localized question to be sure but there are thousands of those on the site. To make the question more useful the OP could make it more generic after getting his answer. For a self-answer you're expected to start with a question that's already sufficiently generic for others to find it useful.

Answer (score 13):

Answering your own question is fine, but the question and answer need to be up to the same standards as every other post, or they will face the exact same consequences as any other post.

If people don't consider your question useful, well researched, clear, appropriately scoped, on topic, etc. they will treat it just the same as any other question with those same problems.

Likewise, if readers feel that an answer isn't a useful solution, isn't clear, etc. they will act appropriately.  Just because the question author thinks that it was the best solution doesn't mean everyone else needs to agree with them.

The one person that felt that you were wrong to self-answer the question was simply mistaken; all of the people that felt that your question/answer just wasn't a useful/quality post regardless of who posted them are quite right to provide the appropriate feedback.

Comment: I feel a strong compulsion to apply extra scrutiny to self-answered questions. I'm not saying I'd downvote or flag for reasons that make no sense... I'd just look a little harder for things that are legitimately wrong. Right or wrong, I doubt I'm alone in that.