# Is it ok in some circumstances to ask for an example to a generic programming problem?

Tags: support, specific-question, scope

My question is a little bit like [Is it okay to just ask for an algorithm to a problem?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271842/is-it-okay-to-just-ask-for-an-algorithm-to-a-problem), but for an example rather than an algorithm.

I think I've gotten better about asking questions than when I started last year, but sometimes I still write questions that I think would be good but apparently aren't.

Today I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29815248/full-text-search-example-in-android) and it was down voted three times. I've been studying Android SQLite full text searches for the last couple weeks, especially the last couple days. I learn best by studying an example that someone else has made but for this topic I could only find one, and it was a whole complex project, not just a bare bones example. I think I really thoroughly researched what was available, and if there is more out there then it isn't easy to find.

I know its bad to ask too broad or general questions ([like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29822943/how-would-i-make-a-gui-phone-book)), especially when there are lots of tutorials out there to teach you how to do it. But is it ok in my case to ask for a basic example when there is such a lack of other examples online?

My other thought is that maybe people thought I was copying a homework question or something. I spent a couple hours writing the question so that it would be as clear as possible, but maybe that made it sound academic. I know the best questions have source code with them, but I don't have much to show yet. Eventually I will solve it, but I haven't yet.

What do I need to change about this question?

Answer (score 17):

The question you have asked is close worthy (in my opinion) for a number of reasons.  It also has some problems with the way it is presented.

First, asking for an example.  By asking for an example, it sounds very close to the close reason

> Questions asking us to **recommend or find a book, tool, software
>   library, tutorial** or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack
>   Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.
>   Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve
>   it.

I realize that you aren't explicitly asking us to point you somewhere off-site, but I could understand someone reading it that way.

Two, your question resembles a "do my work for me" question (and as such feels like it could fall in the "too broad" close reason).  It reads like "I need a tutorial for X.  I need it to do A, B, and C.  If it could do D, E, and F that would be great."  Treat asking a question like you are asking a busy co-worker a question.  How would your co-worker feel if you asked them to take time to stop what they were doing to craft you a tutorial to fit your needs?  I imagine they might be a little annoyed.

Third, the tone of the question sounds more like a proposal rather than a solvable problem.  Using phrases like "I think a good answer here could help a great number of people" and "I will try to make it general enough to apply to a wide audience" sound like a request for a blog post.  SO isn't a place to petition someone to write you a blog post.

Fourth, there isn't a specific problem to solve.  No matter what I give you, you can't verify that it works.  Deciding which answer is the best is not a measure of whether it works or not, but rather whose tutorial you like better.  That hits the "primarily opinion based" close reason, not because you said you want a "best" something, but because there is no way to say any one answer is better than another in a (mostly) objective way.

---

All that being said, could your question be rewritten in a way that makes it a better fit for SO?  I believe so, but it will take some work from you to get something started (and probably multiple questions).  First try something.  Just try making an FTS table.  If your syntax fails, that can be a question, like this (being overly simplistic here):

> I am trying to make an FTS virtual table.  I looked here [link] and I tried
>   this code: [code here]  However it gave me the following syntax
>   error/runtime error/ etc. [error here].  How do I fix this?

Then run with that.  Try the next part of performing an FTS query.  Get as far as you can then ask again once you've done research and got stuck.  Then do the next step.  Rinse and repeat.

After a while you will have all the parts of what would be a good tutorial because you have figured it out yourself (with some SO help).  Then if you still believe the tutorial is worth it, write it yourself!

Like I said above, SO isn't a blog writing service.  It is a place to get help solving specific programming related problems.

Comment: Thank you for your careful answer. I certainly don't want to presume upon the time of busy people by making it sound like I am asking others to do all my work for me. I will continue to work on answering this question myself by breaking it into smaller pieces. In the future I will ask more specific questions unless I already have an answer prepared (Q&A style).

Comment: @Suragch Please don't ask too broad question even if you already have an answer prepared. I'd vote to close such a question even if it is self-answered (for the reasons Becuzz wrote in his answer here). If you think such a tutorial is worth writing: please do so, but this is not the platform for it.

Comment: @Suragch Compare this meta answer: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284779/881272

Answer (score 6):

Regarding [the example question you linked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29815248/full-text-search-example-in-android), it seems to me that a bit more effort at understanding the code could go a long way.

[The blog post you cited](http://blog.andresteingress.com/2011/09/30/android-quick-tip-using-sqlite-fts-tables/) is actually very good.  Much of it describes how to set up demonstration tables, so if you already have tables or already know how to set up tables, just mentally skip over that part.

The important code (which the blog writer specifically highlights) is here:

```
db.execSQL("CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE " 
            + TABLE_WORDS_FTS 
            + " USING fts3(" + COL_ID + ", " + COL_KEY_LABEL + ", " 
            + COL_KEY_DESCRIPTION + " , " + COL_KEY_LANGUAGE + ", " 
            + COL_KEY_TERM + " " + ");");
```

which you then use like this:

```
SELECT * FROM words_fts WHERE words_fts MATCH 'term';
```

I wish more blog posts were like this.  It's completely self-contained; it contains everything you need to set up an example, and tells you how to test it.  He even includes some sample repository classes.  There's no fat in that blog post; there's nothing there that is not useful.

I can't tell you how many times I've seen code examples on the Internet that left something important out because they assumed you already knew about it, or they were simply too lazy to create a complete example (what we call an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)).

If you're looking to do [copy/paste programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_and_paste_programming), I would suggest to you that putting a little more effort into understanding the concepts first is a better approach.

Comment: The blog post initially threw me off because it was creating non-FTS indexes in addition to the virtual table, so I was getting lost in all the new concepts. You're right, though. I think with more work I will be able to get something working myself. I will continue to study that blog. I have a follow up question: If I already had an answer, would my question be appropriate for Q&A style post?