# How long of an answer is "too long for this format"?

Tags: support, specific-question, scope

The "too broad" close reason says:

> There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be
>   **too long for this format**. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

I would like to know how long "too long" is. When I was learning about the StackExchange format I was directed to [this post](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/a/4500) as an exemplary model, but as far as length goes, it seems pretty long to me.

Recently I asked [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29815248/full-text-search-example-in-android) that was getting down votes and close votes (I hope I'm not inviting more close votes by asking this question now). I asked [this SO meta question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291221/is-it-ok-in-some-circumstances-to-ask-for-an-example-to-a-generic-programming-pr) about it, from which I got some good advice about asking better questions. I made a comment that I would try to be more specific with my questions in the future unless I was answering it myself Q&A style. To this someone commented that I should not do that even Q&A style.

Anyway, I've been working for the last few days on answering my original question and I finally posted [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29926430/3681880) today. Is it too long? Is it too much like a blog? Should I avoid answers like this in the future?

Comment: Well, the example you are using is a *spectacularly* long answer, not exactly usual. The point is that we want to avoid questions that require a book-length text to be answered.

Comment: But re your question, I can't comment on the subject matter but from a quick glance, your answer looks fine.

Comment: Note your question is a *bit* on the broad side, but both the question and answer seem like good posts.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have a point, that post is *awfully* long.

That being said, the question is reasonably narrow in scope, and the answering user was a bit... overzealous in their post (not that its a problem, its just that the question didn't demand an answer of such detail).

"Too Long" is subjective of course, but here's a question to which the answers would be too long:

> I need a program that can capture and compare faces. I would like to
>   use C# if possible.

Or this one:

> What do I need to learn to be a good C# programmer?

Or even this one:

> What are all the differences between Java and C#?

And in case you are wondering, yes, I have seen each of those questions, or similar ones, as *actual posts*.

Clearly each answer would *have* to be **insanely** long (a huge program for the first one). Questions on Stack Overflow are expected to expose a specific piece of information, not make you parse through pages of code to find that *one snippet* you were actually looking for. This makes it far more useful and searchable, as well as simply more answerable.

Comment: Additionally the first example would be a bad question per se, since this is not really the place for `I need a program ` questions.